# Understand React Hook useMemo() by Example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand React hook `useMemo()` by converting the below function not to use `useMemo()` hook but I am not getting success nor understanding its inns correctly. The function that uses `useMemo()` maps through an array of objects and returns 5 rows:

```
  const productTableDisplayData = useMemo(
    () =>
      products.map((product) => [
        product.id,
        product.title,
        `${product.title} ${appendToTitle}`,
        product.descriptionHtml,
        `${product.descriptionHtml}${appendToDescription}`,
      ]),
    [products, appendToTitle, appendToDescription]
  );
```

I tried to write the above into the following - but got no success in doing so and the function does not return what the above does:

```
 const productTableDisplayData = 
    () => {
     return products.map((product) => {
        product.id,
        product.title,
        `${product.title} ${appendToTitle}`,
        product.descriptionHtml,
        `${product.descriptionHtml}${appendToDescription}`
      })
}
```

Comment: In your first example, `productTableDisplayData` is presumably the result of that `.map` operation. In the second example, `productTableDisplayData` is a _function_ that will perform that `map` operation when it is called.

Comment: You could simply log productTableDisplayData to see its value. You will have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

useMemo return a value. Not a function. So you need  to update `productTableDisplayData` to:

```
const productTableDisplayData = products.map((product) => {
  product.id,
  product.title,
  `${product.title} ${appendToTitle}`,
  product.descriptionHtml,
  `${product.descriptionHtml}${appendToDescription}`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`useCallback` returns its function uncalled so you can call it later, while `useMemo` calls its function and returns the result.

`useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`.

You have to apply `useCallback` if you try to use the second code block.
Otherwise, Viet's answer is great for `useMemo`